# Returning an object corresponding to a class

Tags: java

So i have 2 classes, and in the class race i have a method ( public Athlete getAthlete(int codAthlete) ) that 
should return the object corresponding to the Athlete with the code passed by parameter, but i am not sure how to 
implement it. Can someone give me a hand?

```
public class Athlete {
    private int codAthlete;
    private String name;

    public Athlete(int codAthlete){
        this.codAthlete = codAthlete;
    }

    public int getCodAthlete() {
        return this.codAthlete;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public String getInformation() {
    return "Code: " + this.codAthlete +
    " Name " + this.name;
    }
}
```

.

```
public class Race {
    private String idRace;
    private Set<Athlete> athletes;

    public Race(String idRace) {
        athletes = new HashSet<>();
        this.idRace = idRace;
    }

    public String getIdRace () {
        return this.idRace;
    }

    public Athlete getAthlete(int codAthlete){
        for(Athlete a: Athlete){
            if(a.getCodAthlete() == codAthlete)
                a.getInformation();
        }
        return (????);
         // Returns the object corresponding to the Athlete with the code passed by parameter.
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of calling `a.getInformation()` , you may just do `return a` . Also you may `return null`  after the loop since no matching athlete has been found.

Comment: And `for(Athlete a: athletes){` instead of `for(Athlete a: Athlete){`

Comment: Naming tip: `id` makes a lot more sense than `codAthlete`. My mind keeps thinking about Call of Duty Athletes